# how to make QWebView open newwindow

Tags: qwebview

i am a new to programming c++ using QT

i have a window which contains QWebView

the problem is that when i enter a website which uses java script ( for  instance : index.jsp)
when the js request newwindow , it does not open ,  it just refresh the page with the same content . when i check the requested link address ,it was like this ( for instance : www.website.com/index.jsp# )

so how  i can open this link in the same QWebView  ?

BTW i tried to enable javascript by this code

```
// in the mainwindow 
ui->webView->settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::JavascriptEnabled,true);
ui->webView->settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::JavascriptCanOpenWindows,true);
ui->webView_2->page()->settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::JavascriptCanOpenWindows, true);
```

and did not solve the problem